# Comment all occurences except the first one using sed

Tags: text-processing, sed

I am trying to comment out all other occurrences except the first one.

original sample.txt

```
one
two
three
two
two
#two
```

sample.txt

```
one
two
three
#two
##two
#two
```

I've only been able to comment out all occurrence. Using:

```
sed -i /two/s/^/#/
```

but this also comments out already commented occurrence. This also comments out the line in which the occurrence is found. How do I get around this? I am testing this on ubuntu baseline image so I can't particularly install anything.

Comment: Why  `##`  in front of the third `two`? Is that because it's the second duplicate of `two`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us what output you want to see.

Answer (score 4):

At least with GNU sed (which is what you should have by default on Ubuntu) you can do address ranges like `0,/pattern/`. So perhaps something like:

```
$ sed '0,/^two/!s//#&/' original.txt 
one
two
three
#two
#two
#two
```

This says "for every line except those between line 0 and the first match of `/^two/`, replace `/^two/` with `#` followed by what you just matched. The empty pattern `//` in the substitution matches the previous regex, and the `&` substitutes the thing just matched - a non-golfed version would be

```
sed '0,/^two/!s/^two/#two/' original.txt
```

Since `^two` is anchored to the start of the line, it doesn't match the already commented occurrence - if that's *not* what you want, remove the `^`.

Comment: After posting this I was able to figure out a part of it except keeping the first occurrence uncommented! If it's okay, can you explain to me what !s means and &

Comment: @Nathan added some explanation

Comment: Standard `sed`: `1,/^two/!{s//#&/;}`

Comment: @Kusalananda doesn't that have an issue that if the pattern occurs **in** line 1 it will match to the second occurrence though?

Comment: @steeldriver Yes, you are correct (I didn't think about that). You'd have to build something else for standard `sed` since you can't use `0` as the start address of the range...

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -p -i -e '$_ = ("#" x $count{$_}++) . $_' your-file
```

produces your expected outcome. It prefixes each line with as many `#` as there have been occurrences of the same line before.

The `-i` option above edits the file **i**n-place (actually the `-i` option found in some `sed` implementations like apparently yours was copied from `perl`).

Comment: in awk: `awk '{for (i = c[$0]++; i > 0; i--)  printf "#"} 1' < your-file`

Answer (score 1):

`sed` is notoriously bad at counting.  It's easier with `awk`:

```
$ awk '/^two/ { if (++count > 1) $0 = "#" $0 }; 1' file
one
two
three
#two
#two
#two
```

This prepends a `#` character to every line that starts with the string `two` after having seen an ignored one such line first.  All lines, whether modified or not, are then printed (via the trailing `1` in the code which could be replaced by `{ print }`).

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what you might want, but if I understand correctly, you want to end up with a file where the uncommented entries are unique, everything else commented.  I don't know how you'll do this but one work around would be keep the original file in tact and end up with another file with the unique ones...

```
$ cat sample.txt | uniq | grep -v ^#  
one
three
two
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `ed` instead of `sed` to edit the file:

```
printf "%s\n" '/^two/+1,$g/^two/s/^two/#two/' w | ed -s sample.txt
```

For every line that starts with `two` *after* the first such line through to the end of the file, (The `/^two/+1,$` address range), put a `#` in front.

Answer (score 0):

Using Posix sed, we can perform the transformation as follows:

```
$ sed -e '
    /^two$/!b
    H;g;s/^\(\n\n*\).*/\1/;x
    s/.//;y/\n/#/
' file
```

**Output**:

```
one
two
three
#two
##two
#two
```

**Explanation**:

For the interesting lines /^two$/ we prefix with a newline, save the newlines into hold, strip one newline,  and turn remaining newlines to hashes.

And in case we don't want to pile on the hashes, we can use the below posixly code:

```
$ sed -e '
    /^two$/!b
    :a;n;s//#&/;ba
' file
one
two
three
#two
#two
#two
```

Answer (score 0):

Since we are off `sed` here's an `awk` variant

```
awk '/^two/{if (t) printf "#";t++}1'  file
```

Just set a flag when you hit your first match and `printf "#"` on every subsequent match before the natural print